# JS Promise - Return some results without resolving the promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm making a function to upload a video with Firebase storage.
I want to get the progress state of the uploading process, and having the success or the failure of this process with a Promise.

Here is the code :

## video.service.js

```
function uploadVideo(generatedFileName, file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebaseStorageReference
      .child("videos/" + generatedFileName)
      .put(file)
      .on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => ???,
        error => reject(error),
        () => resolve(file)
      );
  });
}
```

## video.component.js

```
function uploadVideo() {
    videoService
      .uploadVideo()
      .then(video => success(video))
      .catch(error => error());
};
```

I would like to have some sort of event which will be triggered in the video.component.js file to detect the progress change. But, i still want my promise to be achieve when the file is successfully resolve.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks,

Comment: You could solve it with a callback function that can be called with state-change-information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the firebase documentation:

1. [`put` function returns `UploadTask` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#put)
2. [`UploadTask` provide a way to get updates on the progress of the upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask.html)

One way to achieve your goal is to send a callback as a parameter to `uploadVideo` and use it every time `UploadTask` tells us there is an update about the progress of the upload:

```
function uploadVideo(generatedFileName, file, progressCallback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebaseStorageReference
      .child("videos/" + generatedFileName)
      .put(file)
      .on(
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        'next': snapshot => {
            const percent = snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
            progressCallback(percent);
         },
        'error': error=> reject(error),
        'complete': complete => resolve(complete)
      );
  });
}
```

---

This code is not tested! I only changed their example so it will fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use of a good old callback to attach

```js
function uploadVideo(attachProgressEvent) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let i = 0;

    Array.from(new Array(10)).forEach((x, xi) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (typeof attachProgressEvent === 'function') {
          attachProgressEvent(i, 10);
        }

        i += 1;

        if (i === 10) {
          resolve();
        }
      }, xi * 100);
    });
  });
}


uploadVideo((i, tot) => {
    console.log(`Progress of ${i}/${tot}`);
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('All done');
  });
```